# can't insert and read data in postgresql pdo

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

i've just migrate my database from mysql to postgresql. and my code using PDO. i have searched about how to connect to postgresql with PDO and it works. but i have trouble when called fucntion to create data and read data.i always catch with alert 'unable to create data'  in my code.

but when i called search function, my data from postgresql came out. please help me to solve this problem.

here are the codes :

```
class barang.php 

<?php
class Barang
{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "barang";

    // object properties
    public $id_barang;
    public $nama_barang;
    public $harga_satuan;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    // create barang
    function create(){

        // to get time-stamp for 'created' field

        //write query
        $query = "INSERT INTO 
                    " . $this->table_name . " 

                    id_barang = ?, nama_barang = ? , harga_satuan = ?";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id_barang);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->nama_barang);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->harga_satuan);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    // read products
    function readAll($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page)
    {

        $query = "SELECT 
                    id_barang, nama_barang, harga_satuan
                FROM 
                    " . $this->table_name . " 
                ORDER BY 
                    id_barang 
                LIMIT 
                    {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }

    function Search()
    {

        $query = "SELECT 
                    id_barang, nama_barang, harga_satuan
                FROM 
                    " . $this->table_name . " 
                WHERE 
                    id_barang LIKE :search OR nama_barang LIKE :search ";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $search = $_GET['search'];
        $stmt->bindValue(':search','%' . $search . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;

    }

}
?>
```

Alert unable to create data catches on this code :

```
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// if the form was submitted
if($_POST)
{

    // instantiate barang object
    include 'objects/barang.php';
    $barang = new Barang($db);

    // set barang property values
    $barang->id_barang = $_POST['id_barang'];
    $barang->nama_barang = $_POST['nama_barang'];
    $barang->harga_satuan = $_POST['harga_satuan'];

    // create the barang
    if($barang->create()){
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">";
            echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
            echo "Data barang was created.";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    // if unable to create the barang, tell the user
    else{
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\">";
            echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
            echo "Unable to create barang.";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement with `column=value` series isn't standard SQL, it's MySQL-specific syntax, which is not supported in PostgreSQL. You should use the ANSI-SQL syntax instead:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 
            " . $this->table_name . " 
            (id_barang, nama_barang , harga_satuan) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

EDIT:

The `limit` clause MySQL uses also isn't standard. In PostgreSQL, the [syntax is slightly different](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html):

```
$query = "SELECT 
                id_barang, nama_barang, harga_satuan
            FROM 
                " . $this->table_name . " 
            ORDER BY 
                id_barang 
            LIMIT 
                {$records_per_page}"
            OFFSET
                {$from_record_num};
```

Comment: thank you very much. it works now, and how about select data from database?it stil doesnt work. maybe is there any way to select data on PDo with Postgresql? it will help me much. thanks :)

Comment: thanks for answer my questions. i think i just change the connection to migrate dtabase but the statement should be change too, do you have a reference about postgresql and pdo? if you have please let me know . i want to learn more about it. gbu :).